# How to make multiple images center horizontal and responsive using div?

Tags: html, css

How do I make a line of images within a div responsive? My aim is to have a line of images (centered on the webpage) which scales, depending of the size of the screen. The (2) solutions I have untill now are like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dsslot/mz4xLv5k/), but not good enough. I try to:

- keep it centered on the page
- images should get smaller when the screen is smaller (smartphone)
- stay in one line, so not getting in a vertical lineby resizing
- leave a blank space between the multiple images
- size of the original images shouldn't matter.

I'm not a master of programming, so....

Thanks in advance,

Dennis

```
<div style="width: 100%; clear: center;">
<div style="text-align: center;"><a class="hoverborder" href="" rel="alternate"><img class="img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" width="100" height="70" /></a>
```

```
<div style="float: left; text-align: center;"><a class="hoverborder" href="index.php?Itemid=319" rel="alternate"><img class="img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" width="100" height="70" /></a></div>
<div style="float: left; text-align: center;"><a class="hoverborder" href="index.php?Itemid=318" rel="alternate"><img class="img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" /></a></div>
<div style="float: left; text-align: center;"><a class="hoverborder" href="index.php?Itemid=321" rel="alternate"><img class="img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" /></a></div>
<div style="float: left; text-align: center;"><a class="hoverborder" href="index.php?Itemid=322" rel="alternate"><img class="img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" /></a></div>
```

Comment: Please, PLEASE move your CSS to the CSS panel. That's just ugly and it's difficult to change.

Comment: use ``display:inline-block`` instead of ``float``. Use ``white-space:nowrap`` on the container so that images will not wrap. Use ``text-align:center`` on the container to center the images on the page. Use % on the images' ``height`` and ``width`` to resize them relatively to the window's size. And use ``margin`` to insert space between images.

Comment: Psst... jlowcs... answers go down there.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of ways to accomplish this. They somewhat depend on what's around the images in the page. I tend to avoid floats because they create other challenges and simply aren't necessary.

```css
.image-row {
    text-align: center;
}
.image-box {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 1%;
    margin: .5%;
    background: pink;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0; /* fixes bottom padding */
}
.image-box img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-row">
    <div class="image-box">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-box">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x500" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-box">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-box">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/q2pwLt01/)**

Comment: Thanks isherwood.
the only problem right now is that if the screen is getting smaller, the last image will end up as a second row, but they should always stay in one line and get smaller so they still fit in the screen.
second thing is that if i add a 5th image, this one also ends up on the second row.....

Comment: So you're asking for a bit of CSS that will anticipate any change to your HTML? Mmm-kay. I'm afraid that's impossible. You'll need to rely on your own powers of deduction to some extent. As for this wrapping to two lines, the fiddle works well down to about 150px. If you're on a device with a screen smaller than 150px wide, it's time to upgrade.

Comment: Haha, the upgrade will come with bigger smartphones....
Maybe I'll try it with a menu-like solution, because I use the line of images as a menu whitin a Joomla website. Any sugestions?.